# Can I generate 2 numbers from a single What-if parameter in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm using a **what-if** parameter to filter a table. I'm trying to generate 2 number from this **what-if** parameter, as the visual "slicer" supports "between" selection and other multi-selection options.

[image: What-If parameter showing slicer between two numbers]

When I change from single value selection to multi-number selection, I can't get any value on **Parameter Value**. When I change back to single value selection, I can get the parameter value, as seen on the pictures.

[image: Multi-number selection, no parameter value]
[image: Single number selection, correct parameter value]

Is it possible to use the **What-if** parameter to generate two (or more) numbers with this multi-selection?

PS. I really need to use parameters like this, like a "between slicer", as the top and bottom numbers will be used to filter a couple of different columns with rather complex rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! That's possible!

You can notice that when you create a What-if parameter, the **Parameter Value** measure is created with the code like:

```
Parameter Value = SELECTEDVALUE('Parameter'[Parameter])
```

The `SELECTEDVALUE` function returns a single value from a list, that's why no value is returned when you select multiple ones.

Knowing that, you can create measures to get the `MAX` and `MIN` value of those listed on the parameter, like this:

```
Top parameter = MAX('Parameter'[Parameter])
```

and

```
Bottom parameter = MIN('Parameter'[Parameter])
```